# OpenMP and unbalanced nested loops

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize a simulator written in C++ using OpenMP pragmas.
I have a basic understanding of it but no experience.

The code below shows the main method to parallelize:

```
void run(long long end) {
  while (now + dt <= end) {
    now += dt;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < populations.size(); i++) {
      populations[i]->update(now);
    }
  }
}
```

where `populations` is a `std::vector` of instances of the class   `Population`. Each population updates its own elements as follows:

```
void Population::update(long long ts) {
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < this->size(); j++) {
    if (check(j,ts)) {
      doit(ts, j);
    }
  }
}
```

Being each population of a different size, the loop in `Population::update()` takes a varying amount of time leading to suboptimal speedups. By adding `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)` in the `run()` method. I get a 2X speedup with 4 threads, however it drops for 8 threads.

I am aware of the `schedule(dynamic)` clause, allowing to balance out the computation between the threads. However, when I tried to dynamically dispatch the threads I did not observe any improvements.

Am I going in the right direction? Do you think playing with the chunck size would help? Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: What hardware are you running this on. How many physical cores does it have? How many hardware threads does it support?

Comment: I have several HW machines available. Ranging from 4 cores (8T) to 44 cores (88T)

Comment: Your algorithm is likely limited by memory bandwidth which means it does not scale linearly with the number of cores (though if done correctly it should still scale with the number of sockets).

Answer (score 0):

So there is two things to distinguish: 
The influence of the number of threads and the scheduling policy.

For the number of threads, having more threads than cores usually slows down performances because of the context switches. So it depends on the number of cores you have on your computer

The difference between the code generated (at least as far as I remember) for static and dynamic is that with the static scheduling, the loop iterations are divided  by the number of threads equally and with the dynamic scheduling, the distribution is computed at runtime (after the end of every iteration, the omp runtime is queried with __builtin_GOMP_loop_dynamic_next).
The reason for the slowdown observed when switching to dynamic can be that the loop doesn't contain enough iterations/computations so the overhead of computing dynamically the iterations distribution is not covered by the gain in performance.

(I assumed that every population instance doesn't share data with others)

Just throwing ideas, hope this help =)